# Where to signal 'wrong password' in this signin view?

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on a sign in page in Django, but I am using Userena.  I have attached the view method for the signin in Userena below.  The problem is that since all the views I have written previously to this were MUCH shorter and concise.  I'm having trouble trying to figure out where in this method I would add something in to "do something if password is wrong".  Ideally, what I would like to do is if the password is wrong, trigger a popup in javascript.  I'm guessing I first have to add something to this view method that indicates the password is wrong though?

```
@secure_required
def signin(request, auth_form=AuthenticationForm,
           template_name='userena/signin_form.html',
           redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
           redirect_signin_function=signin_redirect, extra_context=None):


    form = auth_form()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = auth_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            identification, password, remember_me = (form.cleaned_data['identification'],
                                                     form.cleaned_data['password'],
                                                     form.cleaned_data['remember_me'])
            user = authenticate(identification=identification,
                                password=password)
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                if remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(userena_settings.USERENA_REMEMBER_ME_DAYS[1] * 86400)
                else: request.session.set_expiry(0)

                if userena_settings.USERENA_USE_MESSAGES:
                    messages.success(request, _('You have been signed in.'),
                                     fail_silently=True)

                #send a signal that a user has signed in
                userena_signals.account_signin.send(sender=None, user=user)
                # Whereto now?
                redirect_to = redirect_signin_function(
                    request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name), user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('userena_disabled',
                                        kwargs={'username': user.username}))

    if not extra_context: extra_context = dict()
    extra_context.update({
        'form': form,
        'next': request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name),
    })
    return ExtraContextTemplateView.as_view(template_name=template_name,
                                            extra_context=extra_context)(request)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check user present or not like :

```
if user:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
    else:
        # account disabled
else:
    #invalid login detailed
    return response
```

Comment: actually it's return & calling 'userena_disabled' url with 'username' parameter